# Advice about 3D Engine for portable .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

I want to develop a portable C# API for 3D rendering to use with XAML control. ( 3D host between UWP control)
To which 3D engine should I use ?

I already learn OpenGL but i don't know if more High Level API are available.
The idea of the program is to have a 3D Scene builder with some object to add with drag and drop. 
Using xaml for the interface is a constraint.

Do you have any recommendations or advice?

Thank's a lot !

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Oveflow. Sadly questions asking for software/ library recommendation or other off-site resource are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: oh sorry :( Where can i ask this question ?